# Finding k xonnected vertices with wight sum bellow t

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have an undirected graph G(E,V) with weights on the vertices. I need to find every k connected vertices so that the sum of their weight is smaller then a number t. 
The major problem I have is dealing with circles.
Will be happy to get any ideas ... Even if its not a complete algorithn

-----edit-----

so far i had the following ideas (which are not working)..

1. I know that each componnent has a spreading tree, when I look on the root (R) of that tree (tree of k vertices with sum under t) then I have the following options: R has a son and he is a root for such tree with k-1 vertices || R has two sons one is the root of tree with k-2 and another son root of the tree with 1 vertex(the son itself) and so on...
   so to find R I wanted to use dynamic programing. first ill find for each v in V the minimum tree with 1 vertex that v is its root. then 2 .. and by the idea above ill find the rest.
   the problem is, example: if R has only one son u and the minimum tree of k-1 verticees that u is its root contains R, than it turns out that R is not the root of tree of k vertices .. when there is the option that u is the root of k-1 tree (not minimal) that doesnt contains R and W(T(k-1))+W(R) < t...
2. I tried dealing with this problem by building BFS tree with k layers for eac v in V, but then I think im loosing options because the BFS tree dosent contains all edges.

3.thought about maybe to tranform this problem to max flow problem some how but couldent see how to do it.

Comment: Please show and/or explain what you have tried so far. Is "circes" a typo for "cycles" or "circles" (although I'm not sure what exactly would that be in a graph)? In that case, why is that a problem?

Comment: This is a knapsack problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use breadth first search and stop processing nodes when the distance with the sum of weights to the source (denoted by 's') is greater or equal 't'.

Something along these lines (Java style code):

```
private void bfs(Graph G, int s) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<>();
    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++)
        distTo[v] = INFINITY;
    distTo[s] = 0;
    marked[s] = true;
    q.enqueue(s);

    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        int v = q.dequeue();

        for (int w : G.adj(v)) {
            if (!marked[w] && distTo[v] + weights[v] < t) { // preventing going beyond accumulated weight 't'
                distTo[w] = distTo[v] + weights[v];
                marked[w] = true;
                q.enqueue(w);
                edgeTo[w] = v;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The fields I have used above are mostly arrays and their index should be a vertex v (assuming that all nodes in the graph are integer numbers from 0 to n - 1):

```
private boolean[] marked;  // marked[v] = is node v already visited ?
private int[] edgeTo;      // edgeTo[v] = previous edge on shortest s-v path
private int[] distTo;      // distTo[v] = number of edges shortest weights s-v path
private int[] weights;     // weights[v] = weight of v
```

After processing the bfs routine all marked nodes should have a distance less than t.

You can deal with circles by marking the nodes, in order not to re-visit them.

Comment: Your solution doesnt take into account the `k` parameter that sets the number of vertices a solution should exist out of. Also, your solution only runs for 1 source, i.e. can never consist of all solutions for non trivial graphs. Running this iteratively for each node will have a huge time complexity for graphs with many vertices each with many edges

Comment: this will give me the wights off vertices if ill take the shortest path from s to a vertex v. but there are more options